# I cannot log in to the user in GUI on the Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, desktop, gui

When I type the correct password on the login screen and hit the enter key, the screen starts blinking and clears the field for entering the password. After this operation I am not moved to the desktop.

I can log in on the virtual console. What command results to send to you that will help solve my problem?

**Edit:**
I don't know if it will be useful `/var/log/lightdm/`: [lightdm.log](https://pastebin.com/eKhFyUvW) and [x-0.log](https://pastebin.com/r2RuvR00)

Comment: When did this occur? On initial installation? After update? After installing an additional keyboard layout??

Comment: the system worked for a few months so it didn't happen right away, I didn't install an additional keyboard layout, I did usual updates, maybe I installed a theme but it was probably not for that

Comment: What kernel version were you running when this happened?